# Problema ao executar migrations no laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, migrations

Eu estou tentando executar a migrations no laravel e esbarrei no seguinte erro, não sei se e de conexão com o banco de dados o o que pode ser

> ```
> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = mensis and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
>
>  at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:665
>     661|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
>     662|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
>     663|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
>     664|         catch (Exception $e) {
>  > 665|             throw new QueryException(
>     666|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
>     667|             );
>     668|         }
>     669| 
>
>  Exception trace:
>
>   1   PDOException::("PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution")
>       /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70
>
>  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=mysql;port=3306;dbname=mensis", "mensis", "mensis", [])
>       /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70
>
>  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
> ```

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=aqbanc
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No `DB_HOST` é a configuração do endereço para chegar no servidor e você colocou `mysql` está errado, ou é `localhost`(`127.0.0.1`) (que é a maquina local) ou um endereço válido, então onde esta o seu servidor de [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), um exemplo com `localhost`:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost 
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mensis
DB_USERNAME=mensis
DB_PASSWORD=mensis
```

Comment: Poise  ué minha configuração ta toda certa  e não vai no caso eu estou usando o xampp no linux e mesmo baixando  uma aplicação nova laravel não roda a migrate.

Comment: Você colocou a configuração corretamente? @Richardcarlos você leu a minha solução e colocou `localhost` ou `IP` endereço?

Comment: Lembre-se de executar o `php artisan config:cache` após modificar o .env.

Comment: se o seu banco está numa maquina virtual que por acaso se chama "mysql" verifique se existe permissão remota.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic  Minha configuração e essa: 
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=aqbanc
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

Comment: @Richardcarlos o `DB_PASSWORD` é em branco? e a sua maquina de programação é a mesma do banco?

Comment: E sim porque tô usando o xampp

Comment: Eu faria o seguinte, entrava no `Xampp` e criaria uma senha para o usuário `root` e ai esse problema vai acabar. @Richardcarlos ou até um usuário com privilégios para o banco.

Comment: E como eu faço isso no xampp? Desculpa a  minha ignorancia  eu nunca tinha feito isso antes @VirgilioNovic.

Comment: https://tekzoom.com.br/como-alterar-a-senha-do-mysql-do-xampp-e-do-phpmyadmin/ @Richardcarlos utilize esse link